# ANSI colors in log4j mode

Tags: colors, logging

I have some log files which contain ANSI colors, but ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on doesn't work, to get emacs to properly display the colors, and still shows the control codes. Is there another way to either show the colors, or at the very least remove the control codes for the colors.

Comment: Not really related to the question itself: there is a newer [logview mode](https://github.com/doublep/logview) that should be generally more useful than log4j-mode.

Answer (score 1):

See this question and answer, you can do this same thing when opening a log file with ansi colors.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072648/cucumbers-ansi-colors-messing-up-emacs-compilation-buffer

If this is a running log, I would suggest just opening a shell buffer and `tail -f`ing the file which will handle colors.